# Ha’am ha’aretz or am ha’aretz?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, ezekiel--the-book

In yechezk’el (45:16):

> כֹּ֚ל הָעָ֣ם הָאָ֔רֶץ יִהְי֖וּ אֶל־הַתְּרוּמָ֣ה הַזֹּ֑את לַנָּשִׂ֖יא בְּיִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃- Ha’am Ha’aretz.

Yet just a few pesukim later, (46:3):

> וְהִשְׁתַּחֲו֣וּ עַם־הָאָ֗רֶץ פֶּ֚תַח הַשַּׁ֣עַר הַה֔וּא בַּשַּׁבָּת֖וֹת וּבֶחֳדָשִׁ֑ים לִפְנֵ֖י יְהוָֽה׃- Am Ha’aretz.

As far as I can tell, they mean the same thing (a nation of the land), yet one uses the grammar used for noun/ adjective (Ha’am Ha’aretz, like HaShulchan HaGadol) and one uses שייכות (Am Ha’aretz, like Beit HaK’nesset). Why? (Sources please.)

Comment: IINM, the meaning of "a simple person" is post-Biblical.

Comment: Technically, the Hebrew grammar formed much later (see Mishnaic Hebrew) and such forms were pretty legitimate. Don't judge the Tanach by the contemporary rules of the Hebrew language.

Comment: The traditional teaching in relation to Yechezkel 45:16 where the double-Heh is applied, is that it is referring to the Gerei Tzedek, who originally have no possession in the land of Israel because they do not belong to any tribe. The 'Double-Heh' is an allusion to the Heh added to Avraham and Sarah's names. This is also found in Avot in relation to Ben Heh-Heh and Ben Bag-Bag (בג is equated to ה).

Comment: Yechezkel 46:3 is referring to farmers or those with a lesser education.

Comment: Bring sources and I’d accept it as an answer

Comment: For additional insight, see Yechezkel 48:19 and the reference to: "וְהָעֹבֵ֖ד הָעִ֑יר יַעַבְד֕וּהוּ מִכֹּ֖ל שִׁבְטֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃"

Comment: It's not a given that they mean the same thing. *Am Ha'aretz* is used to mean both "the people of the land" meaning "general populace" or it could refer to the local council as in the usage of *am ha'aretz* when Avraham purchases the Cave of Machpela. If it refers to the latter meaning, it is singular which would require the use of the *heh* at the beginning. I'm not saying that that's what the 1st occurrence means, here, as I haven't researched it yet. But, I'm pointing out that you can't always assume that the two mean the same.