# Why isn't המלך המשפט a grammatical mistake?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, shemoneh-esrei, high-holidays

During these ימים נוראים we finish the 11th blessing of the *amida* with the words המלך המשפט. What does this exactly, literally mean? *Melech* and *mishpat* are both nouns, so it would seem that we need a verb or adjective in place (as is the case in the usual formulation of מלך אוהב צדקה ומשפט, or the other *yamim nora'im* addition, המלך הקדוש).

*Gmar chatima tova* to all!

Comment: Related: "[Ha’am ha’aretz or am ha’aretz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101666/1368)"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is in fact dealt with by [Rashi on the spot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.12b.2?lang=en&p2=Rashi_on_Berakhot.12b.2&lang2=en), who says that the first ה is redundant, and this has the same meaning as מלך המשפט, citing scriptural precedents for this phrasing. Basically - this is an unusual, anomalous usage which חז"ל chose for some reason, but the normative way of saying this would be מלך המשפט - king of justice.

Thanks to @rosends for bringing [this discussion](https://avodah.aishdas.narkive.com/B9ClAfXn/what-does-hamelech-hakadosh-mean) to my attention. Note that one commenter there was confused by the parallel to הא-ל הקדוש, but that's incorrect. הקדוש is an adjective and so two letters ה is the normal way to phrase that.

Comment: Ok, but do we know anything, why chazal chose this wording?